# How do you pin your favorite apps to the dash?

Tags: 11.04, unity, unity-dash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I edit which icons appear in the Unity dash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34182/can-i-edit-which-icons-appear-in-the-unity-dash)

how pin your favorite apps to the dash?

eg replacing Firefox - explore the web ("explorar la web") with opera in the initial dash
(when pressing the Super key - Windows key)

yet it must be officially implemented in natty help text appears in gray: Desktop Help »Overview> Applications and windows" "Pin your favorite apps to the dash"