# No Firefox (internet) icon in dash

Tags: 11.04, unity, firefox, unity-dash

Why I have no Firefox icon in Dash (like in clean install of Natty)? My system was updated from 10.10 (and from 10.04 in turn). Preferred app for internet is set to Firefox. It's my most often used application, how to fix this?

[image: Dash]

[image: Preferred apps]

Sorry my Russian locale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since another users dont have that issue, problem was in home dir. I think it was caused by upgrades from 3.0 -> 3.5 -> 4.0 firefox from PPA in the past.

Solved by deletion of some duplicated *firefox*,*firefox.desktop* files from home dir.

Answer (score 0):

The dash should keep track of your frequently used applications. Firefox should place itself in there if you use it a few times.

Comment: Think he means the quick choices that come up when you just press super. Mine is for some reason set to Chrome, although Firefox is my preferred browser (and has been set that way for a long time).

Comment: Yes, that's the problem! I want Firefox here

Answer (score 0):

If you right mouse click on an icon in the Unity dock (I'm confused is this the dash?), you can make it's placement there fixed (see image below).  So the next time you want to run the application, all you do is click on the associated icon.  The reverse can be done for applications you do not want to show up all of the time.

[image: http://i67.photobucket.com/albums/h298/LA_Phantom_photos/Screenshots/dock.jpg]

Comment: this is not the dash :)

Comment: Ahhh...I think I have got it.  I reviewed the original pic and I believe that I now understand the dash.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think that [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35787/how-do-you-pin-your-favorite-apps-to-the-dash) covers yours.

So, press Super, type preferred applications, and change the settings there. Do a restart and it should be fixed, I think.