# Is it possible to customize shortcuts in Unity dash?

Tags: unity, unity-dash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I edit which icons appear in the Unity dash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34182/can-i-edit-which-icons-appear-in-the-unity-dash)

For example, substitute "check email" with empathy, or shotwell with gthumb? Can we do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup your default applications using `gnome-default-applications-properties`

Comment: so it isn't possible substitute the shotwell link with a link to empathy, for example... ok, thanks ;)