# How do I change default dash application for pictures/photos in Unity?

Tags: 11.04, unity, unity-dash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I edit which icons appear in the Unity dash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34182/can-i-edit-which-icons-appear-in-the-unity-dash)

I'd like to change the default application that is associated 'view photos' on the dash.  I can do the web and email ones via 'preferred applications', but not the photos one.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting an arbitrary photo app for the Dash shortcut is not possible in Ubuntu 11.04 but I think it will be possible in 11.10 which will be released in October.

In 11.04, Ubuntu uses the following list in order to fill in the View Photos shortcut.

- Shotwell
- F-Spot
- gthumb
- gwenview
- eog

It will pick the first installed application from this list so if you want F-Spot instead just uninstall Shotwell (and of course, make sure F-Spot is installed). Unfortunately, there is no way to set the shortcut to an app not on this list (without recompiling the source code yourself which is *not* recommended).

Comment: Thank you.  I couldn't have asked for any more detail than that.  The program I want is Bibble---not on the list!  I will wait for more customisation capabilities in future releases.