# How do I change the Super key dash shortcut menu

Tags: 11.04, unity, shortcuts, unity-dash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I edit which icons appear in the Unity dash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34182/can-i-edit-which-icons-appear-in-the-unity-dash)

In 11.04 when I press the "Super" key it brings up a handy "Shortcuts" menu.  Unfortunately, the things that have been placed in that menu are of no use to me.  How can I change the "Shortcut" menu items to the things I really want?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific; if you name the thing you want to get rid off we could be more precise too ;-)

Answer (score 4):

I think you can change the key mapping via Compizconfig-Settings-Manager (ccsm). If you don't find it under Menu -> Preference, then please install it from software center.

Then from CCSM please locate the Ubuntu Unity Plugin, which you can find under Desktop section in Compizconfig-Settings-Manager. Click on it and there you can find an option as "key to show the launcher ". Click on it and select some other key combination as per your choice.

I hope it works for you.

Comment: That's not what he asked. He wants to know how to replace the preset quick choice apps on opening dash.

Comment: excelent! I changed Super to Ctrl+Super, and Alt to Super+Alt, now it doesnt cause trouble with vmware and other applications that require Super to be pressed, thx vm!

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd row in dash are programs that are the default programs (*) or have been used by you. I did not get this in the beginning either but dash is not a search tool but it is a 'you used this alot before so I show it to you now too'-tool: Dash automatically changes content based on what you use.

If you have firefox as a browser in dash and remove firefox, then add chromium dash will not show chromium (you did not use it...) but after using chromium it does.

(*) to change the default have a look at preferred applications for some options:

[image]

Sidenote: you can add activity journal to add some insight in zeitgeist/dash-usage:

[image: Activity journal]