# Change applications displayed on dash's home?

Tags: unity, unity-dash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I edit which icons appear in the Unity dash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34182/can-i-edit-which-icons-appear-in-the-unity-dash)

Is there a way to change the applications in the Dash Home? I'm not sure its called that, but I'm referring to what you get when you press the Super button.

Also, I know that four applications are allowed, but I'm wondering if you can add more, because I have lots of screen space.