# In Unity is there a possibility to add groups and programs to the dash?

Tags: unity, launcher, unity-dash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I edit which icons appear in the Unity dash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34182/can-i-edit-which-icons-appear-in-the-unity-dash)

I don't know how this menu is called but I think you know what I'm talking about. The one appearing when pressing the super key.

By default it shows groups for multimedia, internet, other applications, files and four programs for internet browser, photo application, e-mail and music.

Is there a possibility to add custom groups like "Office Applications" and other programs.

Answer (score 2):

The menu is called `dash` and the icon at the top left is BFB(*) by developers and at the moment you/we can not do alot with arranging icons in dash.

<sub>Big Fat Button</sub>