# How to Create a custom launcher in Unity?

Tags: gnome, 11.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I create launchers on my desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64222/how-can-i-create-launchers-on-my-desktop)

In gnome2 we had this

[image: Gnome 2]

and i don't see any nearlike option for unity! i need to create a custom launcher for a propriate program that doesn't installed thru deb