# Unity dash home menu editor

Tags: unity-dash, menu, home-directory, editor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I edit which icons appear in the Unity dash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34182/can-i-edit-which-icons-appear-in-the-unity-dash)

I did  fresh install to 11.10 and I am unable to find a menu editor.  Please do not post methods offered by 11.04 as none of them work.  This question goes for the 11.10 users who made a fresh install and found an answer.

What I need to do is create a custom menu entry for many aplications.